# In which contexts is MSE equal to RSE squared?

Tags: python, regression

My instructor in a recorded online data science learning platform described MSE as equal to RSE squared. After reviewing the formulas for MSE and RSE, however, I don't understand how or when this might be true. The formulas are:

$\text{RSE} = \sqrt{\dfrac{\text{SSE}}{n-p-1}}$

$\text{MSE} = \dfrac{\text{SSE}}{n}$

If RSE accounts for degrees of freedom, and MSE does not, when/how can MSE be equal to RSE squared?

Comment: I was modeling this question off this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354250/what-is-the-difference-between-rse-and-mse

But if p = 1, the RSE denominator is n - 2, v. MSE's n

Comment: Are they **equal** or do they have the same *minimizer* (in some class of problems)?

Comment: Almost by reading the words, MSE (*Mean Squared Error*) is equal to RMSE (*Root Mean Squared Error*) squared rather than RSE (*Residual Standard Error*) squared

Comment: @Henry There’s still the denominator issue, though.

Comment: @Dave Not when comparing MSE and RMSE

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that they use different denominators? Some definitions use different denominators, and some don't. They would be the same if $\mathrm{SSE} = 0$. $(\sqrt{x})^2 = x$, so the only solution in the other case would be $p=-1$ and degrees of freedom are usually defined as non-negative.